# Xcode 6 Beta 6: 'text' is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a simple tableView application but this code gets an error. Apparently, 'text' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift. I'm using Xcode 6 beta 6. How should I fix this?

```
 cell.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
```

Comment: Directly from the [UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/text): "(Deprecated in iOS 3.0. Use the textLabel and detailTextLabel properties instead.)" ...

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean:

`cell.textLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name`

Comment: Thanks. Just using "text" worked in the earlier betas, so i was confused